# Emulate Google Search queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

Is it possible to emulate **Google Search** queries engine on PHP? It needs to be similar to `MATCH AGAINST`, but it doesn't works on **InnoDB** (and I need to use FK).

I think that it is a complex idea, but maybe there's a library that will do it. I need to make a search like that:

```
$search = new MisteriousQuery();
$search->searchOn('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'address');
$search->searchBy('David');
$search->generateSQL();
```

Basically I need to make a search by relevance and the Google Search engine is very good. Someone have an idea?

Comment: Yep, the Google search engine is good – because they worked on it since 1996.

Comment: The basic idea is you use multiple types of matching (against different pieces of content) and create a 'relevance score' where you tally the amount of times something matches. Like feeela said, this kind of stuff takes hard work to develop.

Comment: Perhaps a simple cosine similarity would suffice in your case?

Comment: You could do a MySql LIKE operator when selecting things.

Comment: Do you search for data stored in you`re database? If so you can use SPHINX search engine :)

Comment: look at Sphinx open source search engine & indexer

Comment: Basically I need a simplified version, of course. Basically I need: a relevance, a match that consider equal or very similar words, accept multi columns search. Maybe the NOT operator too, like `-rodrigues` ignore rows that have `rodrigues` word, but not is the priority.

Comment: Sphinx is a good thing, but I can't use that. :( Well, in all cases, I'm trying to make a library to solve this problem. I just wanted to know if has something done to I not recreate the wheel. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a fuzzy way to match given fields?

One way is to use a better searchengine. For example lucene or sphinx.

Another way is to use SQL to solve this. Investigate in "like" and "n-gramm"/"fuzzysearch".